# Pass parameters to crystal report automatically and export to PDF

Tags: excel, crystal-reports, export-to-pdf, vba

I need to run a crystal report which requires one parameter multiple times. Is there any way to automate running this CR report for a set of different parameters and exporting each report to pdf?

I was thinking of using excel vba but not sure if this is possible and also don't know how to write codes for it. I'm using CR XI but don't have the developer environment installed.

I've looked all over the internet for several days but haven't found a feasible solution.

Any inputs would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Crystal Reports does not have the necessary functionality (i.e. automation) to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could fork my [PsCrystal](https://github.com/craibuc/PsCrystal) project on GitHub and add the missing functionality.  It's a PowerShell wrapper of the Crystal Reports SDK.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not exactly sure how to use that in CR.